# How do I replace a numeric part of a string by another number in Tcl?

Tags: string, tcl

I have a string in a format similar to `1005-abcd` and I want to replace the numeric part of this string by another number and make it like `1008-abcd`.
I can achieve this by using the following -

```
string map {1005 1008} "1005-abcd"
```

But I have these numbers in form of variables. For example, `$source` is `1005` and `$new` is `1008`. When I use the same command like this -

```
string map {$source $new} "1005-abcd"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Braces prevent substitution of the variables. Use another way to give the list and enable substitution. One option:

```
string map "$source $new" "1005-abcd"
```

Another (better) option:

```
string map [list $source $new] "1005-abcd"
```

Comment: Using `list` is recommended; it does the right thing when you happen to use a substring with a space (or other special character) in it.